# In open cart 2.0.2.0 how to change the value passed to the cart?

Tags: opencart

I made some changes in this file catalog>view>theme>default>template>product.
I created a custom textbox where the price of the product changes according to the selection made in the select option.
http://webanddesigning.com.np/ocart/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=72&search=bara
but I cannot pass the selected price to the shopping cart. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Opencart does not pass price info to the cart.  Price is calculated in the library cart class according to options, discounts, specials and other product data in your database.  In your case it sounds like you need to either do this using native options or write a custom option method.

Comment: I want to use the same in build function. I just want to know the variable used to pass the price of the product to the shopping cart(within the product.tpl file) when the "add to cart" button is clicked.

Comment: I've already told you, the price is not passed to the cart.  It's literally the first sentence in my answer.. did you read it?

Comment: I'm really sorry for not being able to be clear.
Can you give me a brief explanation about what happens when the "add to cart" button is clicked?

Comment: I already did... that would be the second sentence.  If you are a php programmer you can look at the system library cart class and it will be pretty clear.  If you are not then it might be time to either learn or hire a developer.

Comment: To calculate something you need a value, right?
Like, when a product is added to the cart, the initial price of our product is calculated and the cart displays the calculated value (e.g. $50.00). From where(or from which variable) is the initial value passed to further calculation ?
If you cant answer this, please don't comment.

Comment: Yes I can answer that.  It's the same answer I gave you twice already.  Not sure if you will believe me if I type it a third time in bold text, but I'll try: **No price value is passed**

Comment: alright then. When we add a product from admin panel, we also insert the price for the product. There must a variable which carries the price of the product from one page to another.
or you can just tell me the function where the tax calculation is done.

Comment: That type of data is stored in (and retrieved from) the database as needed.   There is no single variable where it's stored.. That would depend on the method calling for it.  If you have questions about tax calculations it would be best to open a new question.

Comment: In all honesty though, I get the feeling you will have a bit more luck finding out the things you need on the Opencart support forum:  http://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=190&sid=39d1f69f9f66d99fd6db3c5f7b6b4452

Comment: while adding a product from admin panel I have also attached many select options in the product as you can see. And after making a selection and clicking the "add to cart" button I want the price of the selected option to be shown in the cart.